# Workflow Server Manager SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016, workflow-manager

I have installed **WorkFlow Manager** and the **WorkFlow Manager Client** on each server in our SharePoint 2016 5 server farm and I have registered the **WorkFlow Proxy** to our Site Collection from the `SP Mgmt Shell`. I have imported the certificate into the trust and I have the CU3 updates.

In Service Applications I can see the WorkFlow Proxy is stating its connected however on launching SharePoint Designer I get the message to state that 2013 Workflows aren't configured on the Server.

If I run `Get-WFFarm` and `Get-WFFarmStatus` I can see that its running and I can't see in the ULS logs any errors so I'm a little confused as to why it isn't working.

We are using **SQL 2016** which I've read in some places isn't supported but the only time I've read that is when you are unable to register the proxy to the site collection and you recieve an error in PowerShell.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here, i've also run the `Enable-SPFeature -Identity WorkFlowServiceStore $url -Force` but it hasn't seemed to have done anything.

Anyone had similar issue or is it because we are using **SQL 2016** ? If the answer is **SQL 2016** then what are the specifics for it not working?

Answer (score 0):

1st thing, SQL server 2016 is yet not supported with Workflow manager. being said this, your millage vary because personally i did not see any successful deployment with SQL 2016.

SQL 2016 will be supported in future but no ETA yet.

Comment: Odd, would expect it not work at all if we use SQL 2016. It appears SharePoint is fine the WorkFlow manager App, its only Designer that seems to not recongize it.

Comment: Its hard to stop this...like people still able to install the SharePoint on Client machines...it is more supportablity thing...MSFT haven't tested the scenario...One thing i am thinking...make sure WFM proxy is associated with Web application. check the service connection for that web app

Comment: I understand, its on the list of default service applications. The WorkFlow service states its connected. I get the whole "support" scenario I find it odd that databases are installed, sharepoint connects and assocaties the workflow proxy yet SharePoint designer doesn't work. I would expect in a scenario like this to see a lot more issues before I get to the client stage.

Comment: i agree with you but it is hard to stop it...thats why MSFT use word "Supported".

Comment: Ok, on another collection using the Developer Site template I can use SharePoint 2013 WorkFlows. Thats on the exact same infrastructure so now I'm more confused than I was when I asked the question orginally.....

Comment: Let me explain.if MSFT says product a is not supported with product B...that's mean in intail testing they found the issue and they to verify all the piece of the prod A in order to smooth working...they release future CU which include the support of Product A with prod B..that cu basically fix all compatibility issue.in wfm they add the support for sql 2014 couple of months ago and now they are working to add support for sql 2016 As per user voice.but when don't know...but u will see an update on it it willl be either wfm cu or sql side... nutshell in current situation it may work or may not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, noticed on another site that after running Register-SPWorkFlowService that I can then choose SharePoint 2013 WorkFlow.

Even though the WorkFlow Proxy was assigned in the Service Application Association default group I unticked and removed it from that group and then reticked it and now I'm able to make SharePoint 2013 WorkFlows.

This is with SharePoint 2016 and SQL Server 2016 with CU3 Updates.